# NullPointerException in JSF PrimeFaces' editable DataTable

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf-2, primefaces, objectify

I am having trouble using the editable DataTable from PrimeFaces. I use the same data structure with other model for regular form input with no problems.

The MB receives the object data and prints it, but when it passes to the model it seems to be null.

I am using JSF 2.2, Objectify 4.0b1, AppEngine SDK 1.9.18, PrimeFaces 5.1.

Thank you very much for your help.

The error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.getMetadataForEntity(ObjectifyFactory.java:232)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.WriteEngine.save(WriteEngine.java:71)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.SaverImpl.entities(SaverImpl.java:56)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:33)
    at co.gov.fonada.planeacion.dao.EtapaDAOObjectify.save(EtapaDAOObjectify.java:22)
    at co.gov.fonada.planeacion.mb.EtapaMB.buttonGuardar(EtapaMB.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processCustomListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:87)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processArgListener(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent.processListener(RowEditEvent.java:41)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1070)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1092)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

My code goes like this.

editarEtapas.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="pageTitle">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg['page.title.editar.contrato']}" />
    </ui:define>

    <!--    <f:metadata> -->
    <!--        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{contratoMB.idSelecionado}" /> -->
    <!--        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{contratoMB.editar}" /> -->
    <!--    </f:metadata> -->

    <ui:define name="content">

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
            <p:dataTable id="dataEtapas" value="#{etapaMB.dataEtapas}"
                var="etapa" editable="true" ajax="true" >
                <f:facet name="header">
           Etapas
       </f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{etapaMB.buttonGuardar}"
                    update=":form:msgs" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{etapaMB.buttonGuardar}"
                    update=":form:msgs" />

                <p:column headerText="Opción">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{etapa.opcion}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInputOpcion" value="#{etapa.opcion}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Modalidad">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{etapa.modalidad}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInputModalidad" value="#{etapa.modalidad}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Etapa">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{etapa.etapas}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInputEtapas" value="#{etapa.etapas}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Duración">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{etapa.duracion}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInputDuracion" value="#{etapa.duracion}"
                                style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>



                <p:column style="width:32px">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>


            </p:dataTable>


            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <p:growl id="growl" life="10000" showDetail="true" />
                <p:commandButton value="Crear" id="ajax"
                    actionListener="#{etapaMB.buttonCrear}"
                    styleClass="ui-priority-primary" update="dataEtapas"
                    oncomplete="addRowOnComplete()" ajax="true" />
                <p:commandButton action="#{etapaMB.actualizar}"
                    value="#{msg['button.actualizar']}" styleClass="btn btn-success" />
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Etapa.java

```
package co.gov.fonada.planeacion.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class Etapa implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5521987295840853784L;

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String opcion;
    private String modalidad;
    private String etapas;
    private Integer duracion;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the opcion
     */
    public String getOpcion() {
        return opcion;
    }

    /**
     * @param opcion
     *            the opcion to set
     */
    public void setOpcion(String opcion) {
        System.out.println(id + " setOpcion: " + opcion);
        this.opcion = opcion;
    }

    /**
     * @return the modalidad
     */
    public String getModalidad() {
        return modalidad;
    }

    /**
     * @param modalidad
     *            the modalidad to set
     */
    public void setModalidad(String modalidad) {
        System.out.println(id + " setModalidad: " + modalidad);
        this.modalidad = modalidad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the etapas
     */
    public String getEtapas() {
        return etapas;
    }

    /**
     * @param etapas
     *            the etapas to set
     */
    public void setEtapas(String etapas) {
        System.out.println(id + " setEtapas: " + etapas);
        this.etapas = etapas;
    }

    /**
     * @return the duracion
     */
    public Integer getDuracion() {
        return duracion;
    }

    /**
     * @param duracion
     *            the duracion to set
     */
    public void setDuracion(Integer duracion) {
        System.out.println(id + " setDuracion: " + duracion);
        this.duracion = duracion;
    }

}
```

EtapaMB.java

```
package co.gov.fonada.planeacion.mb;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.faces.model.DataModel;
import javax.faces.model.ListDataModel;

import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import co.gov.fonada.planeacion.dao.EtapaDAO;
import co.gov.fonada.planeacion.dao.EtapaDAOObjectify;
import co.gov.fonada.planeacion.model.Etapa;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EtapaMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8149277260790273299L;

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(EtapaMB.class);

    private EtapaDAO dao;

    private Etapa Etapa;

    private Long idSelecionado;

    private Map<Long, Etapa> Etapas;

    public EtapaMB() {
        System.out.println("debug 7");

        dao = new EtapaDAOObjectify();
        fillEtapas();
    }

    public void actualizar() {
        System.out.println("debug 5");

        fillEtapas();
    }

    private void fillEtapas() {
        System.out.println("debug 6");

        try {
            List<Etapa> qryEtapas = new ArrayList<Etapa>(dao.getAll());
            Etapas = new HashMap<Long, Etapa>();
            for (Etapa a : qryEtapas) {
                Etapas.put(a.getId(), a);
            }

            log.debug("Tamaño de la Lista de Etapa (" + Etapas.size() + ")");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error al cargar la lista de etapas.", ex);
            addMessage(getMessageFromI18N("msg.erro.listar.etapa"),
                    ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Logger getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public static void setLog(Logger log) {
        EtapaMB.log = log;
    }

    public EtapaDAO getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(EtapaDAO dao) {
        System.out.println("debug 4");

        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public Etapa getEtapa() {
        return Etapa;
    }

    public void setEtapa(Etapa Etapa) {
        System.out.println("debug 3");

        this.Etapa = Etapa;
    }

    public Long getIdSelecionado() {
        return idSelecionado;
    }

    public void setIdSelecionado(Long idSelecionado) {
        this.idSelecionado = idSelecionado;
    }

    public Map<Long, Etapa> getEtapas() {
        return Etapas;
    }

    public void setEtapas(Map<Long, Etapa> Etapas) {
        System.out.println("debug 2");

        this.Etapas = Etapas;
    }

    public DataModel<Etapa> getDataEtapas() {
        return new ListDataModel<Etapa>(new ArrayList<Etapa>(Etapas.values()));
    }

    public void reset() {
        Etapa = null;
        idSelecionado = null;
    }

    public void agregar() {
        Etapa = new Etapa();
        log.debug("Etapa a incluir");
    }

    public void editar() {
        if (idSelecionado == null) {
            return;
        }
        Etapa = Etapas.get(idSelecionado);
        log.debug("Vamos a editar etapa");
    }

    public String guardar() {
        System.out.println("debug 1");

        System.out.println(Etapa.getId() + " public String guardar()");

        try {
            dao.save(Etapa);
            Etapas.put(Etapa.getId(), Etapa);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error al guardar etapa.", ex);
            addMessage(getMessageFromI18N("msg.error.guardar.etapa"),
                    ex.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
        log.debug("Etapa guardado con id  " + Etapa.getId());
        return "listaEtapas";
    }

    public void buttonGuardar(RowEditEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar");
//      out.println("Dentro de buttonGuardar Id " + Etapa.getId());

        log.debug("Etapa buttonGuardar");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar try");

            // out.println("Dentro de buttonGuardar Id " + Etapa.getId());
            dao.save(Etapa);
            Etapas.put(Etapa.getId(), Etapa);
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Guardado!",
                    "Etapa almacenado exitosamente."));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar catch");

            // log.error("Error al buttonGuardar Etapa.", ex);
            // addMessage(getMessageFromI18N("msg.error.buttonGuardar.etapa"),
            // ex.getMessage());
            // out.println("EtapaMB buttonGuardar Exception " + Etapa.getId());
            // out.println("EtapaMB buttonGuardar Exception " +
            // ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        // log.debug("Etapa guardado con id  " + Etapa.getId());
    }

    public String eliminar() {
        try {
            dao.remove(Etapa);
            Etapas.remove(Etapa.getId());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error al eliminar etapa.", ex);
            addMessage(getMessageFromI18N("msg.error.eliminar.etapa"),
                    ex.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
        log.debug("Eliminar etapa " + Etapa.getId());
        return "listaEtapas";
    }

    private String getMessageFromI18N(String key) {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages_labels",
                getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
        return bundle.getString(key);
    }

    private void addMessage(String summary, String detail) {
        getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(summary, summary.concat("<br/>")
                        .concat(detail)));
    }

    public void buttonCrear(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        log.debug("Etapa buttonCrear");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        try {
            Etapa = new Etapa();
            // Etapa.setOpcion("Vacío");
            out.println("Dentro de buttonGuardar Id ");
            dao.save(Etapa);
            Etapas.put(Etapa.getId(), Etapa);
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Guardado!",
                    "Etapa almacenado exitosamente."));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error al buttonGuardar Contrato.", ex);
            addMessage(getMessageFromI18N("msg.error.buttonGuardar.Contrato"),
                    ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public List<String> getEtapaList(String query) {
        List<String> results = Arrays.asList(
                "Radicación inicial estudios previos", "Reunión",
                "Solicitud CDR", "Expedición CDR",
                "Radicación a estructuración", "Sale de estructuración",
                "Radicación a jurídica", "EP aprobados", "Publicación de TCC",
                "Recepción observaciones", "Envío invitaciones", "Pliegos",
                "Recepción observaciones", "Cierre", "Evaluación",
                "Traslado y respuesta", "Apertura sobre económico",
                "Evaluación económica", "Traslado y respuesta", "Adjudicación",
                "Firma de contrato / otrosí", "Acta de inicio (PI contratado)");
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> getModalidadList(String query) {
        List<String> results = Arrays.asList("Abierta", "Cerrada", "Directa",
                "Convenio", "Convenio derivado", "Otrosí", "Gerencia",
                "Adición");
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> getReferenciaList(String query) {
        out.println("Dentro de getReferenciaList");

        List<String> results = Arrays.asList("Firma del contrato",
                "Radicación estudios previos");
        return results;
    }

    public List<String> referenciaList(String query) {
        out.println("Dentro de getReferenciaList");

        List<String> results = Arrays.asList("Firma del contrato",
                "Radicación estudios previos");
        return results;
    }

}
```

EtapaDAO.java

```
package co.gov.fonada.planeacion.dao;

import java.util.List;

import co.gov.fonada.planeacion.model.Etapa;

public interface EtapaDAO {



    Long save(Etapa etapa);

    List<Etapa> getAll();

    Boolean remove(Etapa etapa);


    Etapa findById(Long id);


}
```

EtapaDAOObjectify.java

```
package co.gov.fonada.planeacion.dao;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import co.gov.fonada.planeacion.model.Etapa;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;

public class EtapaDAOObjectify implements Serializable, EtapaDAO {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8337700736834254734L;

    @Override
    public Long save(Etapa etapa) {
        System.out.println("debug 11");
        ofy().save().entity(etapa).now();
        System.out.println("debug 11");
        return etapa.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Etapa> getAll() {
        System.out.println("debug 12");
        return ofy().load().type(Etapa.class).list();
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean remove(Etapa etapa) {
        System.out.println("debug 13");
        ofy().delete().entity(etapa).now();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Etapa findById(Long id) {
        System.out.println("debug 14");
        Key<Etapa> k = Key.create(Etapa.class, id);
        return ofy().load().key(k).get();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

Solved with the following

```
            <p:dataTable id="dataEtapas" value="#{etapaMB.dataEtapas}"
            var="etapa" editable="true" ajax="true" royKey="#{etapa.id}">
            <f:facet name="header">
       Etapas
   </f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{etapaMB.buttonGuardar}"
                update=":form:msgs" process="@all" />
```

And...

```
    public void buttonGuardar(RowEditEvent actionEvent) {
    System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar");

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Etapa etapaModel=(Etapa) context.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(context.getELContext(), null, "etapa");

    this.idSelecionado=etapaModel.getId();
    this.Etapa=etapaModel;

    try {
        System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar try");
        dao.save(Etapa);
        Etapas.put(Etapa.getId(), Etapa);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Guardado!",
                "Etapa almacenado exitosamente."));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("debug buttonGuardar catch");
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it, but I dont think it is the best way to do it. Still hoping someone checks my solution.

Comment: Hint: Use a logger instead of `System.out.println()`.